# code for the difference between two date type inputs when clicking a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, date, difference

what is the code for finding  the difference between two date type inputs when clicking a service button in javascript ?
(if admission date and retire date is given and when we click service button the service period should come as alert)

Comment: Would you like to share some code with us?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224834/get-difference-between-2-dates-in-javascript/15289883#15289883

Answer (score 0):

For comparing dates easily i suggest you take a look at using [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

More specifically [moment().diff()](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/)

From the docs here's how you would compare 2 dates and get the difference in days, i'm assuming you are using jQuery.

```
$('.service-button').click(function(){
    var subDate = $('.submission-date').val();
    var retireDate = $('.retirement-date').val();
    parseDateDifference(subDate, retireDate);
});

function parseDateDifference(start, end) {
    start = moment(start, 'YYYY-MM-DDD');
    end = moment(end, 'YYYY-MM-DDD');
    var difference = start.diff(end, 'days'); // this now contains you the difference in days between the dates
    alert(difference);
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @HimanshuTyagi i've updated as suggested thanks for the pointer.